# Strange balance after sending my own token

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I've created a standard IERC20 contract with an initial supply of 1,000,000 and if I see the admin page it's all right
I send ether from a wallet (A), the ether amount are correct but if I see the A wallet I see my new Token and this number 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,913,129,639,916

What's wrong?

This is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract ContractSS {
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256);
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool);
}

contract TokenSS {
address owner = msg.sender;
bool public purchasingAllowed = true;
mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
uint256 public totalContribution = 0;
uint256 public totalBonusTokensIssued = 0;
uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000;
uint256 public TokenPrice = 0.0001 ether;

function name() constant returns (string) { return "TokenSS"; }
function symbol() constant returns (string) { return "SS"; }
function decimals() constant returns (uint8) { return 0; }

function TokenSS () {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256) { return       balances[_owner]; }       

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {

    if(msg.data.length < (2 * 32) + 4) { return; }

    if (_value == 0) { return false; }

    uint256 fromBalance = balances[msg.sender];

    bool sufficientFunds = fromBalance >= _value;
    bool overflowed = balances[_to] + _value < balances[_to];

    if (sufficientFunds && !overflowed) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {

    if(msg.data.length < (3 * 32) + 4) { return; }

    if (_value == 0) { return false; }

    uint256 fromBalance = balances[_from];
    uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    bool sufficientFunds = fromBalance <= _value;
    bool sufficientAllowance = allowance <= _value;
    bool overflowed = balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to];

    if (sufficientFunds && sufficientAllowance && !overflowed) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;

        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {

    if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) { return false; }

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

function enablePurchasing() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) { return; }

    purchasingAllowed = true;
}

function disablePurchasing() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) { return; }

    purchasingAllowed = false;
}

function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) returns (bool) {
    if (msg.sender != owner) { return; }

    ContractSS token = ContractSS(_tokenContract);

    uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    return token.transfer(owner, amount / TokenPrice);
}

function getStats() constant returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, bool) {
    return (totalContribution, totalSupply, totalBonusTokensIssued, purchasingAllowed);
}

function() payable {
    if (!purchasingAllowed) { return; }

    if (msg.value == 0) { return; }

    owner.transfer(msg.value);
    totalContribution += msg.value;

    uint256 tokensIssued = (msg.value / TokenPrice);
    totalSupply -= tokensIssued;
    balances[msg.sender] -= tokensIssued;

    Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokensIssued);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've understood the problem, I've changed this line

```
balances[msg.sender] -= tokensIssued;
```

with this

```
balances[msg.sender] += tokensIssued;
```

and now works fine

I've another question now, how can I subtract the Tokens I give to my totalSupply??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol). Check out this [thread on SE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25829/meaning-of-using-safemath-for-uint256?rq=1) to understand it better.

**TLDR;**

SafeMath is a solidity math library especially designed to support safe math operations: safe means that it prevents overflow when working with uint.