# Meaning of 'using SafeMath for uint256;'

Tags: solidity

Hi I just started to study solidity. Can you tell me what is `using SafeMath for uint256;`?

https://github.com/decentraland/mana/blob/master/contracts/ContinuousSale.sol#L10

Comment: Update from the future: [SafeMath is no longer needed in Solidity v0.8 and above](https://soliditydeveloper.com/solidity-0.8)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`SafeMath` is a solidity math library especially designed to support *safe* math operations: safe means that it prevents overflow when working with `uint`. You can find it in zeppelin-solidity [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol).

From the [official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#using-for):

> The directive `using A for B;` can be used to attach library functions
>   (from the library `A`) to any type (`B`). These functions will receive the
>   object they are called on as their first parameter (like the self
>   variable in Python).
>
> The effect of using `A for *;` is that the functions from the library A
>   are attached to any type.

Hope it helps~

Comment: great answer! I did not know about library. thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @giuseppe-bertone thanks. I did not know 'using' meaning.

Comment: It's very important to note that your arithmetic operations do not become magically 'safe' just by including the SafeMath library and adding the line `using SafeMath for uint256;`. You must also replace each `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` with the equivalent `.add()`, `.sub()`, `.mul()` and `.div()` functions.

Comment: Please note that [Solidity v0.8.0](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/12/16/solidity-v0.8.0-release-announcement/) checks arithmetic operations by default, which means that overflow and underflow will cause a revert. SafeMath is no longer required after v0.8.0.

Answer (score 19):

`using ... for ...` is explained in Solidity's documentation, [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#using-for), and is a way to attach library functions to a given type.

So in your case:

`using SafeMath for uint256;`

...means that the functions contained in the `SafeMath.sol` library can be used directly on objects of type `uint256`.

Taking an [example](https://github.com/decentraland/mana/blob/master/contracts/ContinuousSale.sol#L83) from that contract, here we can see that `weiAmount` is declared as a `uint256`, and we can then directly call the attached `.mul()` function on it, rather that passing the variable as a function argument.

```
uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

// calculate token amount to be created
uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);
```

Comment: thanks! yes. I did not understand '.mul()'. now I got it.